# Returning a value from a block in class method

Tags: ios, objective-c

I would like to create a simple method in one of my helper class that returns an `NSString`, but I can't figure out the right way to return the value. I get this error inside the if statement.

> Variable is not assignable (missing __block type specifier)

```
+ (NSString *) photoCount {

    NSString *numberOfPhoto = [[NSString alloc] init];

    PFQuery *photoQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"PhotoContent"];
    [photoQuery whereKey:@"usr" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
    [photoQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

        if (objects) {

            numberOfPhoto = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [objects count]];

        }
    }];

    return numberOfPhoto;

}
```

What did I wrong? I've tried to return the string directly from the block, but it doesn't helped.

Comment: You need to rethink your logic. You can't return a value from an asynchronous method like this -- the return statement will be executed before the background task calls its block (but this isn't the source of your error).

Comment: The error is because you need to declare `numberOfPhotos` with the `__block` modifier. But "rdelmar" is correct, even if the error is fixed, the code simply won't work as written.

Comment: @rdelmar Do you think it would be smarter to create a method in my VC's file and call it from there?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with where you're calling it; it's fine to do it in a helper class, but you need to do it correctly. You either need to call a delegate method from findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock's completion block, or have the photoCount method have a completion block of its own, which would be executed in the if(objects) clause.

Comment: BTW - why are you using an `NSString` to hold a count value? Use `NSInteger`.

Comment: @rmaddy I'm using it in a text view.

Comment: Then format the number where it is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling asynchronous method, so you cannot return the value immediately, but rather you want to adopt the asynchronous completion block pattern:

```
+ (void) photoCountWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NSInteger count, NSError *error))completionHandler {
    NSParameterAssert(completionHandler);

    PFQuery *photoQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"PhotoContent"];
    [photoQuery whereKey:@"usr" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
    [photoQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (objects) {
            completionHandler([objects count], nil);
        } else {
            completionHandler(-1, error);
        }
    }];
}
```

And then when you call it, it would be something like:

```
[MyClass photoCountWithCompletionHandler:^(NSInteger count, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        // handle the error here
        NSLog(@"photoCountWithCompletionHandler error: %@", error);
        self.textLabel.text = @"?";
    } else {
        // use `count` here
        self.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long) count];
    }
}];

// do not use `count` here, as the above block is called later, asynchronously
```